# jboss remote make web service w/ jboss developer

Tags: linux, web-services, jboss7.x, remote-access, jboss-developer-studio

I have JBoss server on linux and I want to connect remotely from another computer to the web service, but jboss shows me alert:

```
Error: Could not load class [org.gama.tutorial.ws.ImplServico]. Did you specify a valid --classpath?
```

Please help me with a guide